# Why my HomeAsUp icon disappeared after I use search actionview in the actionbar

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar

The attribute in my activity is like below:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

And the menu layout of my menuoption is below:

```
 <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          com.xxx:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          com.xxx:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
          android:title="weibo"/>
```

But if I click the search button and return,the icon of homeasup which I want to use it with navagation drawer would disappear.I do not know why.

Everything will get fine if I remove `actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`.
.

Comment: Did you try to (re)set the HomeAsUp indicator to true with a [listener](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10705138/2668136) on the SearchView?

Comment: @Fllo Yes,I try to set it in the setOnCloseListener,but there is nothing happened

Comment: On emulator or real device and specially what is the API tested?

Comment: Oh yes,it's on emulator,but the fact is if I choose a real device instead,the problem would appear like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360477/actionbardrawertoggle-is-not-setting-drawer-indicator   .Thank you very much

Comment: @MarshalChen did you solved it?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem.  My workaround was to use a transparent 1 pixel icon as my home icon so that I can remove the setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false) method but still NOT have an icon since it is transparent.